# USB key will only be mounted by gparted [?]

Tags: hardware, mount, usb-drive

When I insert by usb key nothing happens (i.e. the drive is not visible). I can mount the USB drive from gparted though (and then it's suddenly recognized).

It's not particular to any USB key. This only happens on my laptop (on the desktop the same key will be mounted upon plugging it in without any problems). Finally, the key is formated as **fat32** and `dosfstools` and `mtools` are installed (through gparted claims otherwise).

what's the catch?

**EDIT** Also, gparted offers me the option to mount the key on "/" : shouldn't that be "/media" (or has this changed ?)

Comment: Have you tried pmount?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/88523/creating-a-mount-point-if-it-does-not-exist/941726#941726 - instructions for installing `pmount` here.  It will mount any external with a file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Alt+F2 open the run dialogue box.

Enter `gconf-editor` and Go To> apps> nautilus> preferences> LOOK AT media_automount and media_automount_open
check the boxes and exit.

[Ubuntu Docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this: ALT + F2 and fill in:  gconf-editor
Then go to apps - nautilus - desktop - volumes visible (If this is set to true, icons linking to mounted volumes will be put on the desktop)

Comment: nop: it was already set to true. when i use gparted to show all flags for the usb key, none of them are checked. Is this normal ?

Comment: Again, once mounted from within gparted all works like usual. It's just that i would prefer to be able to mount my usb keys simply by plugging them in, rather than thru gparted each time.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to try: When the usb is mounted, go to System > Preferences > Startup Applications > Options. Click on the button to remember applications. But before that make shure that all other applications (such as firefox etc) are closed.
Then reboot.

Comment: that didn't help either. One thing that may be of interest: when i mount the keys in gparted a little red bang sign is displayed next to the partition's name. Double clicking it says: "Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this some operations may be unavailable". But then again, at this stage the key is mounted alright and i can access it thru nautilus/the link on the desktop -as usual.